# Prove the following algebraic asymmetric inequality: $\sqrt{3abc(a + b + c)} + 2(a - c)^2 \geq a^2 + b^2 + c^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Consider $a \geq b \geq c \geq 0$ real numbers. Prove that:
> $$\sqrt{3abc(a + b + c)} + 2(a - c)^2 \geq a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$

*Source:* RMM 2022

**Comments & discussion:**

> > A weaker form of the inequality may be obtained by using Newton's 3 variable inequality:
> > $$ab + bc + ca \geq \sqrt{3abc(a + b + c)}$$
> > This means that the new inequality would look like:
> > $$ab + bc - 3ac + a^2 + c^2 \leq b^2$$
> > Which will rewrite as:
> > $$(b - a)(b - c) \leq 0$$
> > Which is obviously true

However, I am unable to reduce the more tough form to a simillar expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $ab + bc + ca \ge \sqrt{3abc(a + b + c)}$, we have
$$\sqrt{3abc(a+b+c)}
\ge \frac{3abc(a+b+c)}{ab + bc + ca}.$$

Using $a \ge b \ge c$, we have
$$2(a-c)^2 = (a - c)^2 + (a - b + b - c)^2 \ge (a - c)^2 + (a - b)^2 + (b - c)^2.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$ \frac{3abc(a+b+c)}{ab + bc + ca} + (a - c)^2 + (a - b)^2 + (b - c)^2 \ge a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$
or
$$\frac{3abc(a+b+c)}{ab + bc + ca} + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2(ab + bc + ca)\ge 0. $$

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$. We need to prove that
$$\frac{3pr}{q} + p^2 - 4q \ge 0. \tag{1}$$

If $p^2 - 4q \ge 0$, (1) is true.

If $p^2 - 4q < 0$, using three degree Schur $r\ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9}$, we have
$$\frac{3pr}{q} + p^2 - 4q
\ge \frac{3p}{q}\cdot \frac{4pq - p^3}{9} + p^2 - 4q
= \frac{(4q - p^2)(p^2 - 3q)}{3q} \ge 0$$
where we have used $p^2-3q = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca \ge 0$.

We are done.

Comment: You beated me on time! I was working on this (in a different way from yours). Well done!! $+1$

Comment: @Laplacian You may post your proof/idea.